# C++ age won't display properly

Tags: c++

What's wrong with my code? it does not display the proper age? 
Example, If I input 1990 as my birthdate it should display 25 as my age, however it displays 1025;

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

     long unsigned x, year;
     long unsigned z;
     year = 2015;
     std::cout << "Year of Birth: ";
     std::cin.get();
     std::cin >> x;
     std::cin.get();
     z = year - x;
     std::cout << "Your age is " << z << std::endl;
     std::cin.get();
     std::cout <<" /n";
     return 0;   

}
```

Comment: Literally every occurrence of  `std::cin.get();` is unnecessary, and the first one is what's causing the error. Remove all of these function calls, and  your program will do what you want.

Comment: To complement user2899162's comment: the first `.get()` removes `1` from the input stream, so `x` is only `990` => 2015 - 990 = 1025. Do yourself a favor and print intermediate values during, that way you will find such errors much faster.

Comment: Also note that newline is `\n` and not `/n`.

Answer (score 2):

Remove every instance of `std::cin.get()` as @user2899162 mentioned, and `/n` does not print a new line, `\n` does.

Edited code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

     long unsigned x, year;
     long unsigned z;
     year = 2015;
     std::cout << "Year of Birth: ";
     std::cin >> x;
     z = year - x;
     std::cout << "Your age is " << z << std::endl;
     std::cout <<"\n";
     return 0;   
}
```

Please make it a point to remove such minor errors by yourself, by printing the values of the variables after the operation you are unsure of.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the statement `cin.get();` in `line:12`.

`cin.get();` will hold the screen until user hits a key and only then continue execution for rest of the program.

So if the user enters 1992 as his year of birth, the first keyboard hit '1' shall be consumed by `cin.get()` and `cin>>x` will only store 992 in x.

Solution:
Remove `cin.get()`

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

As others have answered earlier removing std::cin.get() will solve your problem
and for newline you can also use  std::endl.